# query execution failed for dataset 'Dataset1'. Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: reporting-services

Every time I try to generate a report from SSRS, I always get this error:

[image]

This is my query in DataSet1

```
SELECT [DATE]
      ,[SOURCE]
      ,[DESTINATION]
      ,[REFERENCE#]
      ,[ITEMCODE]
      ,[DESCRIPTION]
      ,[UM]
      ,[PRICE]
      ,[QTY]
      ,[AMOUNT]
      ,[MFG]
      ,[EXP]
      ,[LOT]
      ,[TRANS]
      ,[CONSIGNOR]
      ,[DRDATE]
      ,[ID]
FROM 
    [AcctgCon].[dbo].[DelTrans]
WHERE
    Date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
    AND Source = @source
    AND Destination = @destination
    AND Trans = @transaction
    AND Consignor = @consignor
```

I'm trying to figure out where the error might be, but still can't make it work

Comment: should the # be there in the reference field?

Comment: yes, that's the exact name of the column in sql server

Comment: try removing column [REFERENCE#] from your sql and see if it gives you error.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the '=' sign in the where condition to 'IN' for the parameters you are allowing multiple values for.